# Syntax Highlighting theme for presentations

Tags: powerpoint, syntax-highlighting, presentation

I think a lot of us, at some point, had to make a presentation which included some part of the code related to a project.
I'm having a hard time finding a syntax highlighting theme that will fit very well on a presentation. By that I mean that I will be visible on a projector and it will look good.
I'm trying to find a syntax highlighting theme with those characteristics because I'm trying to do some presentations on a course that will be discussing algorithms using a pseudo C/C++ syntax. So a lot of time, students will see code, and I don't want it to be tiring or boring to watch (referring strictly to the visual part). 
Can somebody point me to such themes or articles that discuss them?
I've tried a lot of keyword combinations, but none fitted such that I would find something useful.

Comment: I really like your idea - I once suffered through a lecture where the teacher was some sort of colorblind and could easily distinguish a "green-yellow" line from a "red-yellow" line. For us the difference was neglibly

Comment: I think it would also suffice if you have seen any public presentations that used a good syntax highlighting theme for code.

Answer (score 1):

After a google search I found [this](http://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/add-code-w-syntax-highlighting-to-powerpoint/) link. I believe you should search for something like

> powerpoint highlight source code

on google.

Comment: The Notepad++ theme looks okayish, as it is not tiring, but I'm still looking for a more eyecandy theme.
I've also tried some keywords alike yours, but you will see most of the articles are just related to "how to copy with format from your favourite editor". That is not the problem that I'm actually looking forward to resolve.